# Using (e.g.) Stanford NLP for retrieving specific “indirect” objects

Tags: semantics, computational-linguistics, verbs, dependency-grammar

I am a computer scientist using Stanford NLP for extracting a Semantic Graph from plain text.
Through this tool I am already getting the [universal dependencies](http://universaldependencies.org/u/dep/all.html) but now I want to get all the possible types of indirect objects through the `nmod` relation.

In Italian we distinguish if the indirect complement is either **motion towards a place** (e.g. I am going *to Paris*), a **“term” complement** (e.g. I gave the book *to Mary*), **placement** (e.g. It was held *in Rome*), **time** (e.g. It was held *in 1999*) **motion from a place** (e.g. I am coming *from Switzerland*), **mean complement** (e.g. travelling *by bike*), **Agent Object** (e.g. It was caused *by a tornado*).

Is there an automatic tool through which I can distinguish such elements programmatically (e.g. via Java / Stanford NLP) by using only the verb alongside with the preposition and some information from the object?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are not indirect objects but obliques. Generally such information is if semantic nature so you can't distinguish most of them without a semantic lexicon.

Comment: Ok, that's because in Italian we call them “indiretti” that could be literally translated as “indirect”, thanks. Is there a way to acheive such semantic lexicon?

Comment: You might be interested in the English version of Vallex, it's a valency lexicon with mappings from syntactic relations to semantic roles (of what the authors call "free modifiers" which roughly correspond to obliques).

Comment: So ok, the only thing is to use something like Vallex or/and Babelnet (where I have the same thing, but without corpora).